# Affine spaces: $P + (Q - P)$ is valid but $P + (Q + P)$ isn't

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm trying to understanding why two points subtracted can produce a vector but adding two points doesn't.

$P = (x,y)$

$Q = [x,y]$

I understand it in the following terms:

$P$ as a point is only relevant if we know exactly where it is and for that we need an origin. $Q$ as a vector is relevant because it is a direction and therefore doesn't require an origin to point the way.

According to the rules:

$2P - A$

is valid because

$P + (P - A)$

$P - A$ gives a vector so it's okay.

$P + P + A$

The above isn't true I understand because... well, that's what I don't understand? Why can we not take the position of $P$ and add the value of point $A$ to it to produce a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A familiar example of an affine space is the space of calendar dates.  The points are dates like "October 1, 2016".  The vectors are date intervals like "3 days" or "-2 days".

You can add two vectors to get another vector: 3 days plus -2 days is 1 day.

You can subtract two points to get a vector: October 1 2016 minus September 28 2016 is 3 days; October 1 2016 minus October 3 2016 is -2 days.

You can add a point to a vector to get another point: October 1 2016 plus 34 days is 3 November 2016.

But it makes no sense to add points. What would you get if you tried to add October 1 2016 and August 13 1956? (Of course you could invent something, but it wouldn't be useful.)

*Some* affine spaces have a way to add points—every vector space can be understood as an example of an affine space, with the vectors serving as both vectors and as points.. But as the calendar example shows, addition of points doesn't always make sense.
Affine spaces are intended to model this more general kind of situation, where you can talk about the difference between two quantities but it makes no sense to ask about their sum.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about coordinates. Just take a blank white paper and draw two dots on it. How would you define the sum of those two points?

One suggestion would be to draw a coordinate system on the paper, read off the coordinates of your two points and add the numbers (like for vector addition) to get the coordinates of third point, which you then take to be the sum. But if you do this, the result will depend on where on the paper you happened to draw the coordinate system, so it's not something that's defined only in terms of the points themselves. In other words, adding two points is not a geometrically meaningful operation.

Answer (score 0):

In an affine space the [subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Subtraction_and_Weyl.27s_axioms) of two points is a vector but the sum of two points is not defined. This is because a vector is used to represent a translation and it must be something different from a point, that can be applied (added) to any point so that we can find another point.  Fortunately given any two points we can find a translation that goes from the first to the second point and this is the vector defined as $B-A$.

Comment: in most cases if something is undefined there's a logical explanation for it, i.e. almost everything where zero is concerned. however I don't understand why it wouldn't be?

Comment: I think I got it from the wikipedia link

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful.